# How to deal with ali.asp hack ?

Tags: asp.net

After research found out the bugs was in FCKEditor.
Now I have updated and in few websites replaced FCKEditor.
How can I resolve and check that my server is clean without any traces behind from the hack?
I found Few images uploaded to a folder named "userfiles1/.."
named ali.asp,...ali.asp(1), with malicious code

Comment: Hi Digant ! Welcome to SO,we are not getting your question properly.can you please explain it briefly...

Comment: I am facing an Security issue with my website, and found that "ali.asp.jpg" contained malicious code which allowed the attacker gain access over my system remotely. I have Removed it but what other steps I can take and how can I be sure no other maliciously code / activity is present in my server. windows 2012